# Retrive data from xml file into a datagridview in c#.net

Tags: c#, xml

I am importing data from an xml file to my datagridview in c#
The problem is that only one row is shown in data grid view i.e it is overwritten .
My code is as follows

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    ds.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\dell\Downloads\ChillerReport.xml");
    dataGridView1.DataSource= ds.Tables[i].DefaultView;
}
```

my xml code is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file:///C:\TechView\XSL\Techview AshraeReport.xsl"?>
 <TraneChillerServiceReport label="ASHRAE Chiller Report">
 <date label="Date">Wednesday, April 17, 2013 4:15:48 PM IST</date>
  <technician label="Technician">sss</technician>
  <job_name label="Job Name">01 17 04 13</job_name>
 <chiller_name label="Chiller Name">trane</chiller_name>
 <reference_number label="Ref Number">01</reference_number>
<location label="Location">ppmf</location>
</chiller_setpoints>
</TraneChillerServiceReport>
```

Please Help

Comment: I see only one row in your xml

Comment: Can you show your `dataGridView1`?

Comment: cant post image here...dont have enough reputation. the data gets overwritten in my datagrid view

Comment: as what you have shown with your code, root tag in your xml will be a table. So If you will go over the loop and change your `dataGridView1`'s `DataSource`, you will end with that situation. In what xml tag do you want your data from xml will be displayed?

Comment: Why are you are setting your datasource in a loop? You will end up with 'ds.Tables[3].DefaultView' as your datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution.

I included a for loop in the following manner and i could fetch all the data.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
{
    ds.ReadXml(@"C:\Users\dell\Downloads\ChillerReport.xml");
    dataGridView1.DataSource= ds.Tables[i].DefaultView;
}
```

This created fetching all the required values.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try this 
In **Code behind**

```
            XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("YourFullXmlFilePath",new XmlReaderSettings());
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

            dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["empdetails"];
            dataGridView1.DataBind();
```

Here is Xml file for Demo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<employee>
  <empdetails id="1" name="sam"/>
  <empdetails id="2" name="robin"/>
  <empdetails id="3" name="victor"/>
</employee>
```